# Speed up Crawling Every File C:\ and hashing using Java 8

Tags: java, performance, io

I am wondering if anyone can help me I am trying to read every file in every directory and create a hash of the file. The code works fine but is extremely slow, I wondering what I can do increase the speed and the performance of the below

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Test fw = new Test();
    fw.crawl("c:\\");
}

public void crawl(String path) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    File root = new File(path);
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (File f : list) {

        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            crawl(f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Name:" + f.getName());
            System.out.println("Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Name:" + f.getName());
            System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            int tempByte;
            while ((tempByte = input.read()) != -1) {
                md5.update((byte) tempByte);
            }
            System.out.println("Hash:" + Arrays.toString(md5.digest()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main drawbacks of the solution you are trying to apply are:

- The I/O streams are never closed: resources are leaking severely.
- The `InputStream` reads data per byte and updates the `MessageDigest` with a single byte, but it would be more efficient when using a buffer.
- The main logic body is using older `File` API, but there are newer tools since Java 7.
- `md5` instance is created for each file, but it can be reused by calling `md5.reset()`.

Here what I can suggest to improve this solution.

The main call will be ridiculously short:

```
public void crawl2(String path) throws IOException {
  Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(path), new HashingFileCrawler());
}
```

`Files.walkFileTree` needs an instance of `FileVisitor` and it executes all the boilerplate of traversing the file hierarchy, we need only to implement our logic. Let's call our implementor `HashingFileCrawler`:

```
public class HashingFileCrawler extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

  private final MessageDigest md5; // only one instance

  public HashingFileCrawler() {
    try {
      this.md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
      // if we enter this catch block, there is definitely something wrong with the running JVM. "MD5" algo should exist by default.
      throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
    System.out.println("Dir: " + dir.toString());
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("File: " + file.toString());
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    try (InputStream fis = Files.newInputStream(file);
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
      int nbRead = bis.read(buffer); // read file data into the buffer for exchange with md5
      while (nbRead > -1) {
        md5.update(buffer, 0, nbRead);
        nbRead = bis.read(buffer);
      }
      System.out.println("Hash:" + Arrays.toString(md5.digest()));
      md5.reset();  // reset MD for reuse for next file
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
  }
}
```

`preVisitDirectory` is called before crawling the files in a directory: it corresponds to the original code under condition `if (f.isDirectory())`.

`visitFile` wraps the main logic of producing a hash for a file, under `else` in the original code.

The size of the byte buffer (2048 here) can be adjusted: try to play with different values to see whether the perfs change.

Comment: You might want to make the buffer size a `final` variable.  That would avoid a magic number in the code.

Comment: @rossum: Indeed, this is yet one more thing to improve. This can facilitate the customization to search for optimal buffer size for the task.